# Python Pandas: Pivot certain columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot a column but keep surrounding columns in tact. Here is an example dataframe:

```
index id week  description
0     1  10-11 failure1 
1     2  10-11 failure2
2     2  10-11 failure3
3     2  10-18 failure1
4     3  10-18 failure1
5     3  10-25 failure3
6     3  10-25 failure3
7     4  10-25 failure2
```

I would like the resulting dataframe to look something like:

```
index week failure1 failure2 failure3
0     10-11   1
1     10-11            2
2     10-11                     2
3     10-18   2
4     10-18   3
5     10-25                     3
6     10-25                     3
7     10-25            4
```

Where the description column has been pivoted and the values of the id column populate the values

After trying:

```
df.pivot(index=["index","week], columns="description",values="id"
```

I get an error of length of passed values is x(length of dataframe), index implies 2

Comment: It looks like `df.pivot(index=['index', 'week'], columns='description', values='id')` or `df.reset_index().pivot(index=['index', 'week'], columns='description', values='id')` if index is not already a column.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: you may need to reset the index of the df in order to access the index for pivot.

```
df.pivot(index=["index","week"], columns="description", values="id")
```

Comment: I get an error of length of passed values is x(length of dataframe), index implies 2

Comment: Are you using a different DataFrame? When use this answer on the DataFrame in the question i replicate the expected output perfectly

Comment: I was able to fix it using df.set_index(['index','week']).pivot(columns='description')['id'].reset_index()